# 8bit PCMU Encoder/Decoder

Tags: java, audio, encoding, pcm, decoder

I have 16 bit PCM audio and I want to convert it to 8bit PCMU. As far as I know 16bit to 8 bit conversion is easy - just drop the last 8 bits from each sample.

I want to know how to convert 8 bit pcm to 8 bit pcmu? Any article or sample code will be great!

This is for a mobile platform where no ready-to-use frameworks are available so I will need to do that with custom implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the wikipedia article regarding the [μ-law algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) .

At the bottom it mentions this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20110719132013/http://hazelware.luggle.com/tutorials/mulawcompression.html) where the author shows how to compress 16 samples to 8 bit PCMU samples in C code. Porting that code to Java is trivial.

Comment: You may also find this article useful: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/dvi/IMA_ADPCM.pdf