# PCMU to WAV conversion

Tags: java, c, audio, wav, pcm

I have an IP camera with microphone. I am capturing the sound using open rtsp library but it is saved in PCMU format. Is anybody aware of libraries (C or JAVA) to convert it to WAV? I couldn't find any.. If not then how could I perform such conversion

Comment: possible duplicate of [8bit PCMU Encoder/Decoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802956/8bit-pcmu-encoder-decoder)

Answer (score 2):

This document [(Recommended Practices for Enhancing Digital Audio Compatibility in Multimedia Systems)](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/audio/dvi/IMA_ADPCM.pdf) contains the pseudocode for converting CCITT (a.k.a. PCMU) to plain PCM WAV.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have managed to do it using sox http://sox.sourceforge.net which I can call from java in the same way as I can call it from the command line.